# hybridauth having issues with jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, hybridauth

Has anyone run across issues using Hybridauth on a jQueury mobile enabled site?
I've got a mobile version of a page loading on mobile detection instead of the regular desktop one, so it's using all the same configuration files and script, but simply refuses to work on the mobile version.

When using the 'dialog' data-role the same dialog page opens over the original, so that I have to close the same dialog twice, and none of the authentication takes place.
But when not using the 'dialog' data-role and using a 'page' data-role instead I get the overlay message "Error Loading Page"

Has anyone run across anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are trying to authenticate via javascript which leads to the crossdomain problem. You have to let the browser redirect the whole page to twitter/facebook/other or open it in another window. Trying to do this inside an iframe leads to the same problem.

At least avoiding js and iframe let's you of the hook with dealing with the crossdomain problem which is very tricky to get right when even possible.

Also the page will redirect back to your page anyway after the user presses login.